# What can be the causes of $(document).on( "click") not firing?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I have a fairly large script and am trying to find out, why

```
$(document).on( "click", function( event ) { alert("hello"); }
```

Is not firing. Is there an easier way to find out why this is not working than removing all other click bindings throughout the script?

Also, I have heard that namespacing is a nice way of keeping event bindings restrictive to a certain plugin.

If so, how would I have to setup event bindings for certain event groups? Do I just replace `click` with `click.thisGroup`?

Comment: also, check the jquery version you are using. I tried the .on() yesterday and turns out i had to use .live() hehe

Comment: yeah, I'm also still learning my ways with on() and leaning on the occasional live()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a complete code, I can only guess some possibilities.:

1. syntax error; you are not closing your handler function definition on your sample code
2. the element you are clicking has a call to `stopPropagation()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()` which prevents bubbling to document thus preventing your on event attached to document

Comment: ok. my console shows up no errors, but the stopPropagation could be a cause.

Comment: ok. nailed it down to a plugin I'm using. Let's see where it stopsPropagation. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an element to click on.

```
$(document).on("click", "someElement", function( event ) { alert("hello"); }
```

Comment: before Jquery 1.7. $(document).bind('click', function() { worked perfectly. I'm pretty sure this also works without specifying an element. Also I need ALL clicks for my routine

Comment: Oh sorry, I assumed you were trying to focus on a single element.  Didn't think there was any reason for a full `document` capture but I suppose it's a valid scenario.

Comment: is it possible to attach this envent to    <body> tag? Would it work the same?